# PTTest is failing and not generating mutation coverage

Tags: mutation, pitest

I want to generate mutation test coverage. I am doing POC on PI Test
but it is not taking my test classes and failing. I have configured PTTest plugin in pom.xml. I checked the target class package name and target test class package name are correct in pom.xml file.

I am getting below error -

```
10:50:29 AM PIT >> INFO : Mutating from D:\IR\workspace\cleanup_trunk\reporterDx-service\target\classes
10:50:29 AM PIT >> INFO : Verbose logging is disabled. If you encounter an problem please enable it before reporting an issue.
10:50:30 AM PIT >> INFO : Sending 0 test classes to slave
10:50:30 AM PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to slave
10:50:30 AM PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 0 seconds.
10:50:30 AM PIT >> INFO : Created  0 mutation test units
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.575s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 02 10:50:30 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/244M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.1.4:mutationCoverage (default-cli) on project reporterDx-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:p
itest-maven:1.1.4:mutationCoverage failed: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.
[ERROR] See http://pitest.org for more details.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.1.4:mutationCoverage (default-cli) on project reporterDx-ser
vice: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.1.4:mutationCoverage failed: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the
supplied classpath or filters.
See http://pitest.org for more details.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.1.4:mutationCoverage failed: No mutations found.
 This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.
See http://pitest.org for more details.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
```

This is my pom.xml file -

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <targetClasses>
            <param>com.mutation.dx.pitestdemo</param>
        </targetClasses>
        <targetTests>
            <param>com.mutation.dx.pitestdemo</param>
        </targetTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

below is my class on which I want to generate mutation

```java
package com.mutation.dx.pitestdemo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class PIDemoImpl implements PIDemo {

    @Autowired
    private PIDemoDao piDemoDao; 

    @Override
    public PIDto getPIDetails(String name, int firstNumber,int secondNumber) {
        int thirdNumber = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        PIDomain piDomain =  piDemoDao.getPIDomain(name, thirdNumber);
        if(piDomain != null) {
            PIDto piDto = new PIDto();
            piDto.setName(piDomain.getName());
            int result = piDomain.getX() + piDomain.getY();
            if(result >= 0 ) {
                piDto.setResult(result);
            }
            return piDto;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

below is my test class-

```java
package com.mutation.dx.pitestdemo;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import com.mutation.dx.pitestdemo.PIDemoImpl;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PIDemoImplTest {
    @Mock
    private PIDemoDao piDemoDao;

    @InjectMocks
    PIDemoImpl piDemoImpl;

    @Test
    public void getPIDetailsTest(){
        String name = "Persistent";
        int firstNumber = 0;
        int secondNumber = 10;
        int thirdNumber = 0;
        PIDomain piDomain = new PIDomain();
        piDomain.setName(name);
        piDomain.setX(2);
        piDomain.setY(2);
        when(piDemoDao.getPIDomain(name, thirdNumber)).thenReturn(piDomain);
        PIDto piDto = piDemoImpl.getPIDetails(name , firstNumber, secondNumber);
        Assert.assertNotNull(piDto);
        Assert.assertEquals(piDto.getName(),name);
        verify(piDemoDao).getPIDomain(name, thirdNumber);
    }
}
```

I am using mockito to mock the objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your filters do not look correct. Pitest expects globs that are matched against the fully qualified name of each class.

Instead of

`com.mutation.dx.pitestdemo`

Try

`com.mutation.dx.pitestdemo.*`

The `*` wilcard should then match all classes in the package.

As of 1.2.0 `targetClasses` and `targetTests` do not usually need to be specified when running from maven - pitest will now scan the project and automatically determine which packages are defined in the project.

Answer (score 0):

For those *new* to **Pitest**, this error also occurs when a build hasn't completed or your test classes haven't been built but you have reason to believe they have.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.1.4:mutationCoverage (default-cli) on project reporterDx-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:p
itest-maven:1.1.4:mutationCoverage failed: No mutations found. This probably means there is an issue with either the supplied classpath or filters.
[ERROR] See http://pitest.org for more details.
```

You may have just completed a `mvn clean` and now you're running `mvn site`.  Or you've made changes to your test code and are trying to run Pitest.  You can get into a situation of inconsistency if your Site lifecycle phase isn't forced to build your test classes. Maybe you're also running Eclipse and it's busy recompiling your classes.

Relax, take a deep breath, do these steps:

1. Make sure you're using a `pom.xml` file on your project that has successfully ran Pitest recently.  Undo recent changes to your `pom` file if you're unsure.
2. Make sure references to the `pitest-maven` plugin in your pom file are all using the same version of the plugin.
3. Wait for Eclipse to stop building your classes (if your project is configured with a Maven Nature)
4. Run `mvn clean`
5. Run `mvn test-compile org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage` or `mvn test-compile org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage site`

### TLDR;

Pitest needs to see that the class files (especially test classes) are fully compiled.  A partial compile will mess it up and produce this same error.